# Strange Behavior in final variable in Java

Tags: java, final

In my java program i have used one final variable.We know that the value of any final variable is fixed and can't be changed.so why this particular program is working fine?Can anyone explain.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    int[] integerArray = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    for (final int j : integerArray) {
    System.out.println(j);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's final *within* the body of the loop - but you're effectively declaring a different variable for each iteration of the loop.

It's as if you'd written this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < integerArray.length; i++) {
    final int j = integerArray[i];
    System.out.println(j);
}
```

Again, we have a "new" local variable called `j` on each iteration of the loop... but each of those variables never changes its value.

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating through the array and printing the values, but you are not attempting to change that `final int j` during the iteration.

A new `final int j` is defined at every step of the iteration. You are not overriding the value in an existing `final` reference.

Doing something like:

```
 for (final int j : integerArray) {
    j = 5; // this is a direct override, you won't be able to do this.
    System.out.println(j);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because in the **for-loop** `j` is declared as `int j`. Which means for **every iteration**, a **new** `j` will be created and its **scope** is the for-loop.

Now each `j` is `initialized` **only once**, which adheres to final keyword. Now the below code generates compilation error

```
  for (final int j : integerArray) {
        System.out.println(j);
        j=0; // error, j is getting initialized twice in for-loop context
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your *enhanced for loop* is equivalent to this:

```
for (int index = 0; index < integerArray.length; index++) {
  final int j = integerArray[index];
  System.out.println(j);
}
```

As you can see, there is no contradiction here.

Answer (score 1):

The actual effective code is something like this :

```
for (for j=0;j < integerArray.length ; j++ )
{
    final int i = integerArray(j); // declaring final i for each iteration
    System.out.println(i);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For each iteration, you are declaring a new final variable. It works fine because you are not changing that variable.

Answer (score 0):

On each iteration it declares new variable. So this is not strange behaviour.